# When read-your-own-writes can fail?

Tags: cassandra, eventual-consistency

I use RL/WL=QUORUM and send two updates, is it possible that next SELECT reads my first update, in some circumstances?

```
CREATE TABLE aggr(
    id  int,
    mysum int,
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
)

INSERT INTO aggr(id, mysum) VALUES(1, 2)
INSERT INTO aggr(id, mysum) VALUES(1, 3)
SELECT mysum FROM aggr WHERE id=1 -- expect mysum=3 here, but is it a must?
```

As I can judge from [here](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=13033243) it is possible even to lost part of the second update if two updates come within same timestamp.

If I work around timestamp problem, can I be sure that I always read what I wrote last time?

Comment: Your link is broken above it seems. Could you update? Also could you add an example read and write query and your table schema if possible to add more detail? Thanks!

Comment: @markc, link is updated, query examples added, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No, assuming your using client side monotonic timestamps (current default, wasn't in past). But it is possible with other settings. I am assuming here that its a single client issuing those two writes. If the 2 inserts are coming from two different servers it all depends on their timestamps.

This is the default for java driver 3.x but if using a version of cassandra pre CQL3 (2.0) you need to provide them with USING TIMESTAMP in your query since the protocol didn't support it. Otherwise the two writes can go to different coordinators, and if the coordinators have clock drift between them the 1st insert may be considered "newer" than the 2nd. With client side timestamps though (should be the default on your driver if using new versions) thats not the case.

Comment: Do I correctly understand that if I use single 2.0 client, RL/WL=QUORUM,  and do NOT use TIMESTAMP option then I can miss second update?

Comment: Correct that is theoretically possible. If the updates are handled by different coordinators and those coordinators clocks are not in sync.  i.e. coordA handles update1 at timestamp7, coordB handles update2 at timestamp5, content of update1 will be returned by the select query.

Answer (score 0):

If you do your updates synchronously with CL=QUORUM the second update will always overwrite the first one. A lower consistency level on any of the requests would not guarantee this.